# Prove that $f$ is continuous and nowhere differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $$ f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\mbox{dist}\left(10^{k}x\right)}{10^{k}} $$ where $\mbox{dist}(u)$ is the distance to the closest integer to $u$. Prove that $f$ is continous, nowhere differentiable function.

---

Using the Weistrass $M$-test, I proved that $f$ is continous. However, I have problem with nowhere differentiable part. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not differentiable because for each k value you will get a different value

Comment: "I have problem with nowhere differentiable part." What have you tried? Choose any point $x.$ How do you prove it is not differentiable at $x$?

Comment: Are you sure about that definition of dist()? The name makes me guess that it's the distance to the nearest integer.

Comment: One simple idea is to fix $u$ and then notice that if $v$ has the same first $n$ digits as $u$ then $|u-v| \le 10^{-n}$ but by choosing arbitrary digits for $v$ fron $n+1$ on you can have $f(v)$ relatively big  (eg choosing digits only $4$ or $5$ from then on) and relatively small wr $f(u)$ (choose digits $0,9$ say) since you control the tail so the ratio $(f(v)-f(u))/(u-v)$ can be made to have different limits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series doesn’t seem to converge. Take for instance $x=0.9$. Then $\text{dist}(10^k x)= 10^k x$, for $k\geq 1$, so $$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\text{dist}(10^k x)}{10^k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x $$

and this clearly diverges.

Comment: You misunderstood what dist means as $dist(10^kx)=0$ in your example ( if $y$ is an integer dist $y=0$ by definition)

Comment: @Conrad - This answer was written before the OP corrected their question, and is in fact what pointed out the error.